# Testing my nginx config. Not sure its working

Tags: nginx

I set just setup my nginx config and was trying to give it a test. I restarted my nginx and was trying to do `GET`s to `/parse/login` and `/login`. Was expecting 503s loading the page a few times real fast.

Hitting `/parse/login` I get `403`s  and hitting `/login` I get `404`s

Just want to verify this works

```
  server {
       listen 8080;

       if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
           set $year $1;
           set $month $2;
           set $day $3;
           set $hour $4;
       }
       access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

       proxy_pass  http://nodejs; # should probably remove this?
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       location / {
           limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;

           proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
       }

       location /parse/login/ {
           deny all;
       }

       location /login/ {
           limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;

           proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
       }

   gzip on;
   gzip_comp_level 4;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
   }
```

Any advice on how to ensure this works before deploying to production?

Comment: Are you expecting the new `location` blocks to `proxy_pass` to `http://nodejs`? You need to add a `proxy_pass` statement in each `location`, and move the other `proxy_` statements into the `server` block, so that they are inherited by all three `location` blocks.

Comment: So each `location` block should include a `proxy_pass  http://nodejs;`? I've updated the config with my recent changes. LMK how they look. I probably need to remove the `proxy_pass http://nodejs;` from the `server` block yeah?

Comment: Yes to both questions, and the configuration is looking ok. I haven't used `limit_req` myself, so I can't comment on the specifics of your test.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The main goal of my config changes were to implement `limit_req` to prevent people from spamming our login links and to deny traffic to bad routes like `/parse/login`. What's the best way to test this once deployed to my release server?